# Problems removing silicone from brick

Tags: brick, silicone

In the process of remodeling the house and there was some "decorative" plywood  attached on both sides of a sliding glass door. It was fastened with masonry nails and seals with silicone around the sides.

After removing the wood with a circular saw, I still have the nails and the silicone left. The former I'm thinking of removing with a dremel as they can't be pulled with any of the tools I currently own.

For the silicone, I'm having a much more difficult time figuring out how to remove it. I started by scraping a small section of it (1 out of the 16 foot of silicone they used), which still leaves a tough film behind and the silicone itself appears to have stained the brick.

Next, I tried using a brass wire brush on a dremel. It barely removed the film from what I can tell and left a brassy finish behind. Finally, I attached a steel wire brush to my angle grinder, while that did the trick in terms of removing the silicone (brick was smooth to touch), it appeared that the silicone residue was burnt black.

Any clues as to how I can remove the rest of the silicone without further damaging the look of the brick? Maybe also save the look of my test section haha

Comment: You can try acid washing the area in question; that's how brick generally gets cleaned. However your freshly washed area will look noticeably different than the rest of the brick so you will likely have to acid wash all of the brick. You could also try pressure washing it.

Answer (score 1):

Products like mineral spirits will dissolve most silicone-based sealer or adhesive products but be sure to test on a small area that is not too visible in case it stains the brick.